# Makefile C Ubuntu - Having problems

Tags: makefile

I have 3 files: **MyLib.h MyLib.c Tester.c**
I've been trying to create the makefile but it is proving difficult.

I can do it when it is only one file, like below where I am compiling Hello.c

I have seen some examples but they seem a lot more complicated than the one I am using below -- which sort of makes sense to me.

```
BINDIR =    /usr/local/sbin
CC =        gcc
CFLAGS =    -O

all:        Hello

Hello:  Hello.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} Hello.o ${LDFLAGS} -o Hello


Hello.o:    Hello.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c Hello.c


install:    all
    rm -f ${BINDIR}/Hello
    cp Hello ${BINDIR}/Hello



clean:
    rm -f Hello  *.o core core.* *.core
```

Please help.

I been typing this every time I turn on my computer, kind of annoying by now.

```
gcc MyLib.c Tester.c -o Tester
```

Comment: What's the objective? Create a library and then link tester to that? Or just create a single binary using Mylib.[ch] and Tester.c?

Comment: It will basically do this: gcc MyLib.c Tester.c -o Tester

Comment: See eg. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604398/compile-multiple-c-files-with-make

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming `MyLib.h` is a dependency for both of your C files, you should have something like this:

```
# Variables

CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -O


# Link executable

Tester: MyLib.o Tester.o
    ${CC} MyLib.o Tester.o ${LDFLAGS} -o Tester


# Compile object files

MyLib.o: MyLib.c MyLib.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o MyLib.o MyLib.c

Tester.o: Tester.c MyLib.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o Tester.o Tester.c
```

and, once you've got the hang of how things work, you can use the automatic variables as your second step in reducing code duplication:

```
# Variables

CC := gcc
CFLAGS := -O


# Link executable

Tester: MyLib.o Tester.o
    ${CC} $^ ${LDFLAGS} -o $@


# Compile object files

MyLib.o: MyLib.c MyLib.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<

Tester.o: Tester.c MyLib.h
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c -o $@ $<
```

where `$@` is the replaced by the name of the target for the current rule, `$<` is replaced by the first (i.e. leftmost) dependency, and `$^` is replaced by the full list of dependencies.

In the above, the bits after the `:` are dependencies, i.e. the target to the left of the `:` will be made/remade if any of the dependencies are more recent than the target. For each of the dependencies, `make` will look for a target for it. So, for the first section, it sees that `MyLib.o` and `Tester.o` are dependencies for your overall executable, and it looks for targets for them, which are provided. Finding the targets, it builds them (if necessary) and then proceeds to build `Tester`.

Note that `CFLAGS` conventionally represents *compilation* flags, so you don't need to pass them when you're only *linking* since no compilation is being done at that point.

Also, if you're struggling with this kind of thing, then simplify, and remove all the additional targets (such as `clean` and `install` and `all`) until you've got the hang of what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Crude but effective:

```
Tester:
    gcc MyLib.c Tester.c -o Tester
```

Better:

```
CC = gcc

Tester: MyLib.o Tester.o
    $(CC) $^ -o $@
```

And I'll just make a guess about dependency:

```
MyLib.o Tester.o : MyLib.h
```

More sophisticated makefiles are possible, but this should do for now.