# How do I compile multiple .c files into one executable

Tags: c, file-management

I am creating a File Management System in my Operating Systems Project.
I have different C files for copying a file, deleting a file, changing extension, displaying content and many more.
Now, I want to run all of these files as one file/program.
Is it possible other than combining all codes into one file?

Comment: Rename the `main` of each and write an overarching `main`.

Comment: ...and look at `make` to compile all the source modules and link them into a single executable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Compile multiple C files with make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604398/compile-multiple-c-files-with-make)

Comment: Any half-decent C build system supports a linker.  I suppose that is the hazard of creating your own OS, having to invent everything from scratch.  Make it so.

Comment: How is it possible that you have an operating systems project yet do not know anything about the **linking of multiple translation units**?!

Comment: @AnttiHaapala it's likely a school project. Most school's these don't don't really focus much on C unfortunately, so it could be only OP's second or third time using C, and it's possible he's never had to compile more than one file.

Answer (score 4):

`main()` should exist in only one file.

Then you just compile and link them all together:

`gcc copy.c delete.c extension.c list.c your_app.c -o you_app`

This is usually managed using Make.